# Does thrift persist unknown fields/bytes when it deserializes and serializes back again?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, thrift

So the example case for this is:

I have the type Message. It is passed between server A -> B -> C
Now let's say version 2.0 of the Message is created that has a couple of new fields/ids.
Servers A and C know about this new format, but server B is still using the old one.
All servers deserialize, inspect, serialize and send the message.
Assuming that A is populating all fields (both V1.0 and V2.0 of Message), will C see the populated fields of Message V2.0?

I know that protocol buffers supports this. I wanted to know whether Thrift supports it as well. (on a quick test I did in C#, the answer is **no** but just wanted to check with everyone)

As an example of the Message code, here it goes on IDL:

```
struct Message { // V1.0
  1: i64 Id;
}
```

.

```
struct Message { // V2.0
  1: i64 Id;
  2: string Content;
}
```

Will server C see Message.Content that was populated in A?

Comment: Did you try adding an optional field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

Regarding Protocol Buffers, it is also important to notice that according to the documentation the Python version of the generated code does not support this.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order -
*"If a message has unknown fields, the current Java and C++ implementations write them in arbitrary order after the sequentially-ordered known fields. The current Python implementation does not track unknown fields."*

Comment: What makes you so sure thrift does not? http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/ claims it does.

Comment: Well at least Python and C++ bindings don't save unknown fields for now

Comment: Well, apparently the "Thrift - the missing guide" is simply wrong: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201204.mbox/%3CCACK7Cy6GgDharG=HBm5dyt75xpCmBVkVZnG3f73bdd-JmqK_vQ@mail.gmail.com%3E Sorry for the noise.